# Phone Bluetooth Wireless Microphone

Tags: python, audio, bluetooth, microphone

I am looking to turn my phone into a wireless microphone.

This requires making a two part program.  The first program would use the sound input from the microphone on my smartphone and sends it via bluetooth to my computer.  The second program would be on my computer and treat the bluetooth sound source as a microphone.

I know this is possible because there is a program which does this and works (http://www.wirelessorange.com/womic/install.html) however this undesirable steps like putting my windows computer into test mode to install a driver.

It seems like it should be easier as bluetooth is commonly used to stream audio and bluetooth microphones (ie headsets) are not uncommon.  I am familiar with python so I'd like write the program in this language, but a reasonable internet search has not led me to anything useful yet.

I am specifically looking for guidance on two things.
1) Getting audio from a bluetooth stream
2) Telling the windows computer that the audio stream is coming from a microphone.

Comment: Its to make a wireless microphone.  I figure that most of the ground work should have been laid for doing this via bluetooth.

Comment: Ah, I see, I misread the question. I thought you were asking about recording from a Bluetooth microphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done any network programming before? From what I've read bluetooth comm is a "simple" a client/server setup. So basically you will:

1. Connect (pair?) a server (your pc) to a client (your phone) via bluetooth
2. Pass data from your phone to your server
3. Take the incoming data and convert it to audio
4. Feed the audio to an app that knows how to handle it

I know this doesn't answer your question exactly, but it was just too large for a comment :). Good luck. I will try along when I get home, but I have to dig up my bluetooth dongle.

**References**:

[Bluetooth Programming with Python 3](http://kevindoran1.blogspot.com/2013/04/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3.html)

[Python and Bluetooth](http://homepages.ius.edu/RWISMAN/C490/html/PythonandBluetooth.htm)

Comment: Since the microphone is actually a smartphone, I'd consider encoding it as Opus or Vorbis before transmission.

Comment: I would have to disagree with you on encoding before transmission. A pc is much more powerful than a phone. So encoding on the device and then sending might eat up too much time and the user may experience stuttering or a delay in data. Of course this is hardware dependent (no hardware requirements were supplied so I am just assuming). If the phone is capable of efficiently, cheaply (in terms of CPU), and quickly encoding then by all means go for it. Otherwise let the pc do that.